# Linux dlerror returning error message from dlopen that I can't explain

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen

I am having trouble with the dlopen function in C++/Linux.

```
void * hsiftgpu = dlopen("/full/path/libsiftgpu.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

I would assume that any errors that come out of dlerror() would tell me about not being able to find/open libsiftgpu.so. Here is the code where I check for errors:

```
if(hsiftgpu == NULL){
    std::cout << "Could not load libsiftgpu.so" << '\n';
    fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
    return 0;
}
```

Instead, it tells me this:

```
dlopen failed: libcudart.so.6.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not super familiar with file handling in Linux, so I could be missing something obvious. I'm wondering if I need to reset something before calling dlopen, or perhaps libsiftgpu.so is calling libcudart.so.6.5? Either way, this error message doesn't make much sense to me.

I have tried adding the path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (even though it's not recommend for security, I just wanted to see if it would work) and /etc/lib.conf.so/ I also checked to make sure that both the executable and the .so library are compiled in the same ELF-64 format.

I have run out of ideas of things to check, and I can't explain the error message. Any guidance or possible explanations are appreciated.

Comment: If you type `ldd /full/path/libsiftgpu.so`, you should find a list of all libraries imported by `libsiftgpu.so`. Any which don't have an absolute path will have to be located and added to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. There's probably more to it than that, but alas I've not done much work with libraries on Linux.

Comment: I ran ldd and libcudart.so.6.5 appears with an absolute path. However, that file is a symbolic link pointing to libcudart.so.6.5.14 (which happens to be in the same directory. If my executable needs to point to the real file and not the link, I'm not sure how to adjust that.

Comment: On OS X, see `install_name_tool`. On Linux, see http://nixos.org/patchelf.html

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a case of the executable pointing to the 32-bit library when it should have pointed to the 64-bit library. I gave points to everyone who commented.